# Install error for Mysql-Server

Tags: server, 16.04, mysql, phpmyadmin

I try to install mysql-server and phpMyAdmin, after first instalation i have an error for log with user root ...and after this, error #2002 - No such file or directory. Ok, I tried to uninstall mysql-and reinstall. I successfully removed mysql (I think...hope), but now, when i try to install i have this error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can solve that?

I searched for this error over 12 hours and don't find a proper solution.

Thank you for help !

Comment: Please edit your post to include 1) Ubuntu version 2) The command you used for  installing the packages. .... ? Did you remember running `sudo apt-get update`  ?

Comment: Firstly, thank you for reply @Knud Larsen, i try to install mysql with sudo apt-get install mysql, and yes, i use sudo apt-get update. The UBuntu version, is 16.04.   I don't want to reinstall ubuntu, but....maybe, exist one command to "repair" or "restore to default"? I have dual boot system and my laptop have UEFI, and grub was a huge problem to install. I don't want to repeat "experience"...thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely a problem database in your /var/lib/mysql.  You can perform these steps to ensure you are performing a clean install.  After a successful clean install you can systematically bring in your previous databases or configurations.

First clean the failed install with:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-*
```

then remove or rename the configuration directory and mysql database directory.  Since your mysql database directory may contain previous databases that you don't want to lose, rename it (this is the /var/lib/mysql folder).

Perform these steps:
from the directory `/etc` execute:

```
$ sudo mv mysql mysql.old
```

from the `/var/lib` directory (this is your database directory) execute:

```
$ sudo mv mysql mysql.old
```

Now perform your normal mysql install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

If you had databases in your previous `/var/lib/mysql` directory you can use the following to get them back.  After bringing them back you can perform regular commands to rebuild/check the tables:

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
$ sudo mv mysql mysql.new
$ sudo mv mysql.old mysql
$ sudo service mysql start
```